# Removing sequential values from a vector, but not iteratively

Tags: r

I'm looking to subset a vector to where there are no sequential numbers. However, if there is a sequence of more than two sequential numbers, then only every second sequential number is removed, since removing that number will disrupt the sequence.

e.g. 1,2,4,6,7 would give 1,4,6

e.g. 6,7,8,9 would give 6,8

This is easy to do iteratively, but iterating over 10M+ elements is incredibly slow:

```
x <- c(1,2,4,6,7,8,9) # Ideal output is c(1,4,6,8)
    
for (i in 2:length(x)) {
   if (!is.na(x[i-1])) {
      if (x[i] == x[i-1]+1) {x[i] <- NA_integer_}
   }
} 
      
x[!is.na(x)]
```

Is there another solution that would significantly faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using convenience functions `collapse::seqid` and `data.table::rowid`:

```
library(collapse)
library(data.table)

x[rowid(seqid(x)) %% 2 == 1]
# [1] 1 4 6 8
```

Seems faster on a longer vector:

```
x = rep(c(1,2,4,6,7,8,9), 1e7)

system.time({
  seq_id = data.table::rleid(x - seq_along(x))
  obs_id = unlist(lapply(split(seq_id, seq_id), seq_along))
  r1 = x[obs_id %% 2 == 1]
})  
#   user  system elapsed 
# 112.77   55.99  177.11 

system.time({
  r2 = x[rowid(seqid(x)) %% 2 == 1]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   8.03    5.97   10.23 

all.equal(r1, r2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the fantastic `data.table::rleid` to generate an ID for each sequence, then keep only the odd numbered elements within sequence. This should be quite fast, though more optimization is certainly possible.

```
disrupt_seqs = function(x) {
  seq_id = data.table::rleid(x - seq_along(x))
  obs_id = unlist(lapply(split(seq_id, seq_id), seq_along))
  x[obs_id %% 2 == 1]
}

x <- c(1,2,4,6,7,8,9)
disrupt_seqs(x)  
# [1] 1 4 6 8
```